# Jenkins+fastlane fails with "Missing password for user"

Tags: macos, jenkins, fastlane

#### TL;DR

What's the simplest, secure, step-by-step approach to giving Jenkins 2.x access to the credentials needed for `fastlane` + `sigh`?

#### Context

I inherited a Jenkins 1.x installation and decided to upgrade to 2.x. We have several iOS projects that were building and pushing to HockeyApp/TestFlight without issues, but I had some free time and I figured it'd be better to upgrade from 1.x to 2.x now rather than having to do 1.x to 3.x later.

Not knowing how the original installation had been done, it seemed safest to just use the packaged installer, so I downloaded the binary for 2.32.3 and stepped through the wizard.

#### Problem

In order to test the upgrade, I logged into the web interface, navigated to an iOS project managed by Fastlane, and clicked "Rebuild last". The build failed almost immediately:

```
Missing password for user devuser@example.com, and running in non-interactive shell

+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|                     fastlane summary                     |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                              | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying required fastlane version | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform                    | 0           |
| 3    | xcversion                           | 0           |
|     | sigh                                | 0           |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+

...

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.25.0/credentials_manager/lib/
credentials_manager/account_manager.rb:125:in `ask_for_login': [!] Missing
password for user devuser@example.com, and running in non-interactive
shell (RuntimeError)

...
```

After quite a lot of googling, I've tried following a few suggestions, all with no luck. At this point I'm concerned that I'll just end up breaking things because all of the solutions I've encountered are multi-step, across multiple domains (jenkins, keychain, shell commands), and lacking in any what-could-go-wrong-when-trying-this-solution-and-how-to-recover context.

In short, I'm almost at the end of my rope. Or, as the saying goes, I've got just enough rope to hang myself…and I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting these environment variables.

**FASTLANE_USER**: Your App Store Connect / Apple Developer Portal user, if your/fastlane/setup accesses App Store Connect or the Apple Developer Portal (e.g. submit a TestFlight build, create a profile, …)

**FASTLANE_PASSWORD**: Your App Store Connect / Apple Developer Portal password, usually only needed if you also set theFASTLANE_USERvariable

To generate a web session for your CI machine, use
fastlane spaceauth -u user@example.org

This will authenticate you and provide a string that can be transferred to your CI system. Copy everything from—\nto your CI server and provide it as environment variable named **FASTLANE_SESSION**

**FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD**:
You need to provide an application specific password if you have 2-factor enabled and use pilot or deliver to upload a binary to App Store Connect

For further details refer this https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#environment-variables-to-set

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheers, Sumit. I've moved on from that job, so the issue no longer affects me. I have no way to validate your response, but I do hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Add a secret text credential called FASTLANE_PASSWORD which will keep the password for that user. in non interactive mode you wont be able to write anything in the console, that's the reason you need to do it before.

also if you have Two Step Auth then you will also need to keep FASTLANE_SESSION

Comment: Where do I need to add FASTLANE_PASSWORD variable?

Comment: add as variable in build process

Comment: Storing unencrypted password as an env var is like the worst hack ever!

Comment: how's that a hack @BadmintonCat ? there is this "secrets" which whole purpose is actually to do this thing because they are not visible during builds triggered by PRs e.g. and they can keep private information.

Comment: Not sure I get your drift. Fastlane fails for me if I don't directly define the password per FASTLANE_PASSWORD env var in the pipeline script. That makes it impossible to share the script on SCM/etc. There must be a better way to access the password securely.

Comment: but you add it to env or to secrets? As the latter is the answer that I got from Bitrise folks.

also there is answer https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/two-factor-authentication-for-apple-id-itunes-connect-testflight-deploy/1180 for such cases and more over on their board

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this while searching for an answer to the same problem. Not sure why people reacted negatively to Shiroo's answer, as it provided me with a start.

Basically, you need to set the [FASTLANE_PASSWORD and perhaps the FASTLANE_SESSION (if you are using Two-step auth)](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/) values.

To do so, you can either export them before calling fastlane, or add them to your system's global properties as follows:

[image]